# Not able to render react functional component

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to setup a basic react application(Hello World) on my laptop. I am using react and react-dom ( version 15.5.4) alongwith babel, webpack and yarn to run/test it.

I am getting **Uncaught ReferenceError: Button is not defined** for a pure function component that I have defined in App.jsx. 
Here are the content + the application directory structure I have used.

**App.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';


/*
export default class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <h1>Hello World</h1>
            </div>
            );
    }
}*/

const Button = () => {
    return(<button>Go</button>);
};

export default Button;
```

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './components/App.jsx';

//ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
ReactDOM.render(<Button />, document.getElementById('test'));
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>React App Setup</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- <div id="root"></div> -->
    <div id="test"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Directory Structure**

```
<root_directory>
|_client
       |_components
                  |_App.jsx
       |_index.html
       |_index.js
```

Please let me know, if the package.json, webpack config and .babelrc file content is required as well.

The browser console shows the below error.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Button is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (index_bundle.js:12891)
    at __webpack_require__ (index_bundle.js:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (index_bundle.js:30981)
    at __webpack_require__ (index_bundle.js:20)
    at module.exports (index_bundle.js:66)
    at index_bundle.js:69
```

Comment: In your `index.js` there is no binding/variable named `Button`.

Comment: Yes, got it working. Thanks!

Comment: If you got it working, please add an answer to your question explaining how you did it, so that people who find your question when searching for their own problems can be helped. :)

Comment: I missed the binding for the Button component. Just realised that zerkms has also pointed out the same thing.